# Can we have 2 with_items in ansible in a single task

Tags: ansible

Below is the condition

```
- name: Find the image
  slurp:
    src: "{{ IMAGE }}"
  register: slurp_results

- name: Upload image
  shell: |
    skopeo copy -docker-archive:{{ item }}.tar docker://{{ URL }}/TESTIMAGE
  with_items: "{{ (slurp_results.content|b64decode).splitlines() }}"
```

The above code works.

But I would need "TESTIMAGE" also to be replaced as {{ item }} like below.

```
skopeo copy -docker-archive:{{ item }}.tar docker://{{ URL }}/{{ item }}
```

How to define 2 with_items in a single shell task with 2 different slurp results

Comment: What if you just used `{{ IMAGE }}` in place of `{{ item }}` in your task?

Comment: If I use `{{ IMAGE }} ` then I need to define as variable, But I need to use 2 with_items - one for defining `docker-archive:{{ item }}.tar` and other for `{{ URL }}/{{ item }}`. How to achieve this ?

Comment: 2 with_items variables in single task

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can by using the `subelements` module. [Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) is a link. Try going by this example:

```
- name: Setup MySQL users, given the mysql hosts and privs subkey lists
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    password: "{{ item.0.mysql.password }}"
    host: "{{ item.1 }}"
    priv: "{{ item.0.mysql.privs | join('/') }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ users }}"
    - mysql.hosts
```

Users is referred to as item.0 and hosts as item.1 and so on.